# How to create custom grid with nestable sileder in bricks builder?

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, splidejs

I'v tried to create a custom grid layout with nestable slider, i want to set a grid in desktop screen and normal slider in mobile screen (one slide per page).
I did use the custom option field.
but it is not working

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaNni.png)

I'm expecting grid layout

thanks for the help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.